# Method to display a lead inserted from apex custom controller in salesforce

Tags: apex

I've written a page for the sales team, and they can insert a new lead from a search lookup... Now, I want to also provide a link or commandbutton to show the new lead in salesforce, maybe right to the recently viewed page or right to the lead by itself. I believe this is called a standard salesforce page that I want to link to. I know I read it somewhere how to do it, so I know its possible. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
aLead.Company=CompanyName;
aLead.FirstName=FirstName;
aLead.LastName=LastName;
aLead.Phone=Telephone;
aLead.email=email;

insert aLead;
```

Now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've called `insert aLead`, the `aLead` variable will be modified to contain the new ID of the record.  The link to a detail page for a record is just your Salesforce domain `/` the record ID.  You can either provide a link on your page using `'/' + aLead.ID`, or call an action which returns a `PageReference.`  Such an action can either instantiate the `PageReference` using `new PageReference('/' + aLead.ID)`, or you can use `new ApexPages.StandardController(aLead).view()` if you would like to avoid hardcoding the URL, or would like to link directly to the edit page (change `view()` to `edit()`).